# Did something break with epitools treatment of factor()?

Tags: r, r-factor

There are some issues with some examples of the "epitools" package, for example with the `epicurve.dates` function.

Here is a simple example of an epidemic curve (by days, with `epicurve.dates`)

```
sampdates <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), Sys.Date(), 1)
x <- sample(sampdates, 100, rep=TRUE)
epicurve.dates(x)
```

This is the resulted plot :

[image: plot]

Nothing is ploted, and if we look in the `epicurve.dates` code we can see that the problem happened when it try to encode the date vector as a factor. Only `NAs` are produced.

```
format <- "%Y-%m-%d"; before <- after <- 7
dates0 <- as.Date(x, format = format)
min.date <- min(dates0, na.rm = TRUE) - before
max.date <- max(dates0, na.rm = TRUE) + after
cdates <- seq(min.date, max.date, by = 1)

> factor(dates0, levels = cdates)  
 [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [24] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [47] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [70] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
 [93] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
51 Levels: 2013-12-25 2013-12-26 2013-12-27 2013-12-28 2013-12-29 2013-12-30 2013-12-31 2014-01-01 ... 2014-02-13
```

In the `?factor` help we can read :

> If x[i] equals levels[j], then the i-th element of the result is j. If no match is found for x[i] in levels (which will happen for excluded values) then the i-th element of the result is set to NA.

But when I test if the x[i] equals to levels[j], it's all TRUE ...

```
> sum(dates0 %in% cdates) == length(dates0)
[1] TRUE
```

What's wrong here ?
(It works for example with `factor(dates0, levels = factor(cdates))`)
This example was from the official `epicurve.dates` documentation then I guess it used to worked, I looked for changes of the `factor` function on http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html for example but I find nothing.

Did something change ?

Comment: Maybe a change to `match`, which is called by `factor`? `match('2014-01-20', as.Date('2014-01-20', format='%Y-%m-%d'))` returns NA.

Comment: Yes you are right the error happen with the `match` function in the `factor` code. The x parameter is convert to character (`x <- as.character(x)`) while `levels` are always Dates, and then the match produces NAs.  Thank You.  
Something changed or did the example always been wrong ?

Comment: Narrow it down for us: what old and new versions of R are you using? and what old and new versions of epitools? Do you only see changed behavior in epitools? Or widely, with other packages?

Comment: No response whatsoever after four years, I'm voting to close as too vague. The title was misleading, it suggested `factor()` broke, not just epitools treatment of `factor()`. Looks like this was the [dev branch somwehere between 0.5.7 and 0.5.8](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/epitools/)